# missing jars when publishing a web app to glassfish with eclipse juno and maven integration

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, maven-3

I use eclipse juno with GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3(java EE6), m2e and maven 3.0.4.
When I create a war file by 'mvn package' command and deploy it to a glassfish,
the war file works just fine.

However, when I publish a web app to a glassfish from the server view of eclipse,
the web app fails.
I guess the reason of this failure is that publishing from eclipse is not configured correctly
to get jars from my maven repository and then jar files in eclipseApps//WEB-INF/lib directory are missing.

Can I configure eclipse to use a maven configuration when publishing a web app to a glassfish?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer 
"anyway I solved the issue by adding following row Properties > Deployment Assembly: /target/myapp/WEB-INF/lib -> WEB-INF/lib"
in 
[Glassfish Deployment out of Eclipse Helios SR2 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154828/glassfish-deployment-out-of-eclipse-helios-sr2-fails)

Thanks.