# Eclipse glassfish plugin not publishing maven dependency jars to ear lib folder

Tags: eclipse, maven, glassfish, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm using the Eclipse "Internal Glassfish 3.1.2.2" server with the Eclipse Glassfish plugin (http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno). I'm also using Maven with the m2e Eclipse plugin. The Glassfish plugin correctly deploys my EAR modules to the Internal Glassfish, but it does not deploy my dependency jars, which I believe should end up in a folder called "lib".

I found a partial solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005101/missing-jars-when-publishing-a-web-app-to-glassfish-with-eclipse-juno-and-maven), which is to add my maven target lib folder to the EAR Deployment Assembly (double-click in the Deploy Path box to edit). This works, but m2e (or m2e-wtp) undoes the config change when I do Maven > Update Project.

There ought to be a cleaner solution. The Eclipse Ear Module Assembly dialog has a field to name the "EAR library directory", so it's aware of the lib folder. Where does Eclipse EAR assembly (without Maven) look for jars to put in the lib folder? I assume the Glassfish plugin is looking in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following steps to find the source of the problem:

1. Take Eclipse out of the equation and build EAR on command line using Maven, does it turn out ok? If not, look for a solution in your pom.xml.
2. If ok so far, open Eclipse and perform Maven -> Update Project. Then export EAR using Eclipse (look for EAR export wizard under File -> Export). Did the exported EAR turn out ok? If not, file a bug report for m2e-wtp plugin. It is still pretty raw, so it wouldn't be surprising if it doesn't setup Eclipse metadata correctly in some cases.
3. If ok so far, then it is time to look for a problem in Glassfish plugin. I doubt that you will get this far, but if you do I will help you to follow up.